# Eigenvalues for a 2nd Order Ode

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

I have the following problem. Let,
$$x''(t)=- \frac{3x}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$$
$$y''(t)=- \frac{3y}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$$
$$x(0)=0, y(0)=2, x'(0)=1, y'(0)=0$$

I have converted it to a system of 1st order odes:

\begin{align}
x_1 &\equiv x, \\
x_2 &\equiv x_1', \\
y_1 &\equiv y, \\
y_2 &\equiv y_1'.
\end{align}

So the system system will consist of 4, first order, coupled ODEs in 4 variables. It will look like the following
\begin{align}
x_1' &= x_2, \\
x_2' &= \frac{-3x_1}{\left( x_1^2 + y_1^2 \right)^{3/2}}, \\
y_1' &= y_2, \\ 
y_2' &= \frac{-3y_1}{\left( x_1^2 + y_1^2 \right)^{3/2}}.
\end{align}

I have applied a numerical method to the system and obtained a reasonable solution curve. Now I need to find the eigenvalues at t = 100. Below is the Jacobian matrix I got from the system, but the eigenvalues Matlab is producing are not strictly complex with real part 0... Is my Jacobian wrong?

\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
    \frac{-3(-2x_1+y_1)}{(x_1^{2}+y_1^{2})^{5/2}} & 0 & \frac{9x_1y_1}{(x_1^{2}+y_1^{2})^{5/2}} & 0    \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
    \frac{9x_1y_1}{(x_1^{2}+y_1^{2})^{5/2}} & 0 & \frac{-3(x_1-2y_1)}{(x_1^{2}+y_1^{2})^{5/2}} & 0
  \end{bmatrix}

Comment: The solution is periodic and stable. So no eigenvalue should have positive real part..but I am getting one...help!